# how to run Pycharm twice OR many times from terminal Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, intellij-idea, pycharm

I would like to open many windows or at least twice.

I have two screen monitors and want to open a window on every monitor.

I can run it but open a one window.

Comment: When you say "many windows" you mean for different projects or have parts of the UI on other monitors? Second case @drum Link should help you. If you want separate windows for separate projects, you can just select "Open Project" in the File Menu in Pycharm and the IDE will ask you if you want to open in "New Window" or "This window". Select new and you have a separate instance of Pycharm with the second project.

Comment: thanks for both you, work it with me.